# SBT Error downloading io.spray:sbt-revolver

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-plugin

```
(update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading io.spray:sbt-revolver;sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.12:0.9.1
[error]  Not found
[error]  Not found
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/spray/sbt-revolver_2.12_1.0/0.9.1/sbt-revolver-0.9.1.pom
```

```
not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/spray/sbt-revolver_2.12_1.0/0.9.1/sbt-revolver-0.9.1.pom
```

Why this artifacts were removed? Is this artifact available in another repository?

Comment: https://www.scala-lang.org/blog/2023/04/20/sbt-plugins-community-repository.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting this error because https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases is currently down. This is being tracked in https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/7202